# ASP.net Web Application HTTP Post Database Synchronization

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, post

I am working with a client to setup database synchronization for a program that they use. The program is called [Aljex](http://www.aljex.com/); it is Software as a Service.

Aljex has an API for database synchronization which gives me very little information (and zero examples). The part that is in question is as follows:

> Throughout the day changes are sent to the customer’s database server using HTTP post from Aljex. All data changes sent from Aljex to the customer during the day are sent using a 
>   standard HTTP post request containing the data for a single record. The parameters of the HTTP post will include a parameter indicating the name of 
>   the table for the data, and an action code indicating the appropriate action to perform using the data (create, update, or delete).

I currently have a winhost.com site hosted for this client using ASP.net Web Application (C#). The goal is to synchronize the Aljex database with a database that I can read/write in order to add functionality to the program.

**Question:**
What do I need to handle these post requests in ASP.net? I am experienced with Web Forms and the other standard web items in ASP.net, but I have not utilized any of the following items, and I'm not sure which is needed for this:

- AJAX-enabled WCF Service
- ASP.NET Handler
- ASP.NET Module
- Generic Handler
- WCF Data Service
- WCF Service
- Web Service
- (*Or can I pull this of with a Web Form?)*

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to skin a cat.

**Option 1**

Write a basic asp.net handler that gets the data, parses it, creates a json  string of the submitted post parameters and by using some convention logic to calls an internal service that processes the json string.

**Option 2**

Write a basic MVC3 application that acts as a proxy with a single controller and action.  It gets the data, parses it, creates a json  string of the submitted post parameters and by using some convention logic calls another url of a REST service that provides CRUD operations to your resources.

You can easily develop a REST service using ServiceStack or Web API.